# Requiring Git-like "commit messages" for destructive SQL Server queries

Tags: sql-server-2008

We're constructing a database to be used for development efforts for a financial engineering team. The vast majority of the queries run on the database will be `SELECT`; destructive queries (and inserts) should be run on a quarterly basis, when new data is entered and/or revisions to old statements are released.

I wondering whether it's possible to enforce that users enter a Git-style "commit" message every time a data-changing query is run (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and the related `ALTER`), and if so, how to go about setting up such a feature.

Comment: Are you set on having a SQL Server only implementation? If not, it seems like it would be fairly easy to set up a simple application that uses a sql server user/pass and logs information on the query (user, commit message, timestamp, etc) before passing it through to the server. You could then remove insert/update/delete permissions from the user's logins.

Comment: For a SQL Server only option, look into Instead of triggers. You can create a trigger on all tables to look for a recent entry in your "commit comments" table for the current user and cancel the update/print an error message if a suitable record is not found. Your users would then have to enter this comment before they can get an update to go through. It should work, but I think this option is a bit klugey.